# In C#, why isn't one mock (Moq) returning what it is supposed to?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq, return-value

I have the following code I wish to test:

```
// Snipped for brevity

public DocuSignCallbackHandler(
                ContractDAO contractDAO,
                ContractLister contractLister,
                SalesforceOpportunityProvider salesforceOpportunityProvider,
                IEnvelopeService docuSignEnvelopeService,
                IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
                IImageSaver imageSaveClient,
                ISalesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator salesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator,
                SalesforceContractResolver salesforceContractResolver,
                SfContractWriteDataFactory sfContractWriteFactory
            )
        {
            _contractDAO = contractDAO ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contractDAO));
            _contractLister = contractLister ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contractLister));
            _salesforceOpportunityProvider = salesforceOpportunityProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(salesforceOpportunityProvider));
            _docuSignEnvelopeService = docuSignEnvelopeService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(docuSignEnvelopeService));
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
            _imageSaveClient = imageSaveClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(imageSaveClient));
            _salesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator = salesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(salesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator));
            _salesforceContractResolver = salesforceContractResolver ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(salesforceContractResolver));
            _sfContractWriteFactory = sfContractWriteFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sfContractWriteFactory));
        }


        public async Task<ContractBase> UpdateDocuSignStatus(string contractNumber, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            ContractBase contract = await _contractLister.GetByContract(contractNumber)
                ?? throw new IllegalContractOperationException($"Service does not have a contract numbered { contractNumber }.");

            DocusignPdfResult docuSignPdfResult = await GetPDFfromDocuSign(contract, 0, cancellationToken);

            contract = docuSignPdfResult.ImageLoadId != ""
                ? AddSignature(contract, docuSignPdfResult)
                : throw new IllegalContractOperationException($"Result is in an unexpected state: StatusCode: {docuSignPdfResult.StatusCode}, ImageLoadId: {docuSignPdfResult.ImageLoadId}");

            contract.SfCacheCtrId = docuSignPdfResult.SalesforceContractId;

            ContractBase result = await _contractDAO.Update(contract, cancellationToken);

            // NOTE: In real life, this works, 
            // but in my unit tests, this value is always null.
            return result;
        }

// Snipped for brevity
```

Please ignore that this class has far too many dependencies; I know that.

My test looks like this:

```
[Fact]
        public async Task TestUpdateDocuSignStatusShouldMarkContractsSigned()
        {
            // Arrange
            AutoMocker mocker = new();
            DocuSignCallbackHandler handlerUnderTest = mocker.CreateInstance<DocuSignCallbackHandler>();
            ContractBase testContract = new()
            {
                ContractNumber = ContractNumber,
                EnvelopeId = EnvelopeId,
                ContractHistory = new()
                {
                    new()
                    {
                        User = "Fred"
                    }
                }
            };
            mocker.GetMock<ContractLister>()
                .Setup(x => x.GetByContract(ContractNumber))
                .ReturnsAsync(testContract);
            mocker.GetMock<IEnvelopeService>()
                .Setup(x => x.GetEnvelope(EnvelopeId, It.IsAny<Func<SessionUrls>>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(new MemoryStream());
            mocker.GetMock<IImageSaver>()
                .Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<ImageEnvelope>(), CancellationToken))
                .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new List<ImageUploaderSaveResponse>() {
                        new()
                        {
                            Id = ImageLoadId
                        }
                    }))
                });
            SfOpportunity testOpportunity = new()
            {
                AccountId = AccountId
            };
            mocker.GetMock<SalesforceOpportunityProvider>()
                .Setup(x => x.GetOpportunity(testContract, CancellationToken))
                .ReturnsAsync(testOpportunity);
            SfContract testOutboundContract = new();
            mocker.GetMock<SfContractWriteDataFactory>()
                .Setup(x => x.CreateFor(testContract, testOpportunity, It.IsAny<ImageUploaderSaveResponse>()))
                .Returns(testOutboundContract);
            mocker.GetMock<SalesforceContractResolver>()
                .Setup(x => x.ToJObject(testOutboundContract))
                .Returns(new JObject());
            List<SaveResponse> testSaveResponses = new()
            {
                new()
            };
            mocker.GetMock<ISalesforceCacheSyncDataManipulator>()
                .Setup(x => x.Insert(It.IsAny<IList<SalesforceRecord>>(), It.IsAny<DataManipulationOptions>(), CancellationToken))
                .ReturnsAsync(testSaveResponses);

            ContractBase finalContract = new()
            {
                ContractNumber = "2325235325"
            };

            // NOTE: This mock seems to be ignored.
            mocker.GetMock<ContractDAO>()
                .Setup(x => x.Update(It.IsAny<ContractBase>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(finalContract);

            // Act
            ContractBase resultContract = await handlerUnderTest.UpdateDocuSignStatus(ContractNumber, CancellationToken);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(finalContract, resultContract);
        }
```

Usually, Moq is working as expected, and my mocked out dependency methods are returning the values I want.

However the last mock within the "arrange" section seems to be ignored.
As in the current incarnation, leveraging `It.IsAny()` for both parameters, I would expect it should always return the value of `finalContract`, but in fact, the return value of `ContractDAO.Update()` is always `null`, exactly the same as if I leave that mock out of the test code.

For whatever it may be worth, the concrete method I wish to mock out looks like this:

```
// Snipped for brevity

public ContractDAO(ContractDatabaseSettings contractDatabaseSettings, ILogger<ContractDAO> logger, IMongoDatabase mongoDatabase)
        {
            _contractDatabaseSettings = contractDatabaseSettings ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contractDatabaseSettings));
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            _mongoDatabase = mongoDatabase ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mongoDatabase));
        }


        public async Task<ContractBase> Update(ContractBase inputContract, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                await GetCollection()
                    .ReplaceOneAsync(
                        contract => contract.Id == inputContract.Id,
                        inputContract,
                        cancellationToken: cancellationToken
                );
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Tryng to save data for Contract {ContractNumber}.", inputContract.ContractNumber);
                return null;
            }
            return inputContract;
        }

        private IMongoCollection<ContractBase> GetCollection() =>
                    _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<ContractBase>(_contractDatabaseSettings.ContractCollectionName);

// Snipped for brevity
```

As suggested by @Ermiya Eskandary, I can actually fix this by rearranging the order in which things are mocked out, for example, making this the first instead of last thing mocked out, like:

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task TestUpdateDocuSignStatusShouldMarkContractsSigned()
        {
            // Arrange
            AutoMocker mocker = new();
            ContractBase finalContract = new()
            {
                ContractNumber = "2325235325"
            };

            mocker.GetMock<ContractDAO>()
                .Setup(x => x.Update(It.IsAny<ContractBase?>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(finalContract);

// etc.
```

How is this dependency different from any of the other dependencies, for which mocking always works as expected?

Why should the order make a difference?
Since this is the last mock which will be applied, why should it be itemized first (or at least, not last)?

Comment: Is it the "last" mock always? Switch the order please - does that make a difference? I don't think it will but hey, it's a suggestion. Also can you please add what `ContractDAO` looks like (minimal enough so that the problem is still reproduced)?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, thanks for the quick response.  I didn't think switching the order would work, but in fact I made this the first thing I mocked out instead of the last and it worked!!!!  If you want to post that as an answer, I can accept it, though I'd love to know why.  As for ContractDAO, even though I don't think this shouldn't be necessary  since we want to mock it out, I'll add it above.

Comment: Hm - you're welcome! In that case, go back to the original and then move the initialisation of `handlerUnderTest` further down - AKA initialising the handler after you've mocked all your objects. Does that still work? And does `ContractDAO` have any dependencies itself?

Comment: I restored the original order, except moved `DocuSignCallbackHandler handlerUnderTest = mocker.CreateInstance<DocuSignCallbackHandler>();` to last and, yes, this still works.  :-)  As for the dependencies of ContractDAO, yes, I've added them to the question above.

Comment: I thought so! Will write up an answer soon to satisfy curiosity :)